# golang fiber bodyparser to parse Time

Tags: go

in my project I am using fiber bodyparser to parse json received by my endpoint. I can parse ints and strings, but what if I need to parse Time? Consider the following code:

```
app.Post("/post", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
payload := struct {
    Name      string    `json:"name"`
    Email     string    `json:"email"`
    StartedAt time.Time `json:"startedAt"` //<==== error here
    ExpireAt  time.Time `json:"expireAt"`
}{}

if err := c.BodyParser(&payload); err != nil {
    return err
}

return c.JSON(payload)
```

}

I am receiving a string in 01.01.2001 12:00 format, but getting the following error:

`json: cannot unmarshal \"\\\"01.01.2001 00:00\\\",\\\"expireAt\\\":\\\"0...\" into Go struct field requests.Campaign.startedAt of type time.Time"`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Date should be passed in ISO string format (.toISOString() in js or something). It would be good if it were mentioned in official docs somehow.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious, how did you figure this one out? I was stuck on this for months. Had to write something more ludicrous just to get around this error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with Go and as with most golang things, this is such a frustrating but easily solvable issue on google's part.

In my case, I just left it as a string since I was using a validation library and then only manually parsed to `time.Time`.

It's very frustrating because you'd not expect this stupid behavior from such a matured language.

The validation library: https://github.com/gookit/validate

I used the `date` filter (https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gookit/validate@v1.4.6#IsDate)